# How to use stoppable http connection using lwuit?

Tags: java, java-me, lwuit, midlet

I want to have a http connection in my J2ME application using Lwuit which will have a timeout, can manually stop the request with a button, and a loading dialog while it is processing. I tried thread for HTTP connection but even when I try to interrupt the thread, the connection is still running.Can anyone help me with a example ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to stop an HTTP connection in MIDP. LWUIT4IO provides an API to kill a connection via the kill method which effectively just discards the thread and closes the IO streams it is using. There is a timeout flag in MIDP but it doesn't always work and there is no indication of when the timeout should elapse.

See LWUIT's see [this](http://lwuit.java.net/nonav/iodocs/com/sun/lwuit/io/ConnectionRequest.html#kill%28%29), I don't have a sample of killing but there are several samples of using LWUIT4IO.

Comment: i tried of closing HTTP connection and IO stream ,but it was still running

Comment: Did you use the kill method like I mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

What about the `STOP` Command variable ? Look at the Javadoc about it.